# 動的に追加したCardViewのmarginが反映されない｡

Tags: android, android-layout

`LinearLayout`に`CardView`を動的に3つ`Horizontal`で追加したのですが､子Viewの`CardView`のmarginが反映されずに､ カード間の隙間が表示されません｡  どうすれば､marginを表示できるのでしょうか｡
以下に､XMLとView追加ロジックの概略の1部を示します｡

**View追加ロジック**

```html
LinearLayout relative = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_items);
CardView itemLayout = (CardView)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.relative_and_recommend_item, null, false);

/*View定義*/

relative.addView(itemLayout);
```

**CardViewのXML**

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    /*content*/
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Viewを追加するLinearLayout**

```html
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/relative_items"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/background"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inflate`メソッドの第二引数を指定することにより、子の`LayoutParams`が反映されるようになります。

```
LinearLayout relative = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_items);
CardView itemLayout = (CardView)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.relative_and_recommend_item, relative, false);

/*View定義*/

relative.addView(itemLayout);
```